# Create Cube & Dimension from SharePoint 2010 List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-analysis-services

I want to Create cube and dimension from SharePoint List and want to generate result using MDX on SharePoint List, so Please anyone can guide me how to import SharePoint 2010 List directly to SSAS ?

Please note : I don't want to use Custom Database e.g. import data from SharePoint List to Custom Database using SSIS using example of URL which are below.

http://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2011/06/how-to-use-a-sharepoint-list-as-a-data-source-in-your-ssis-package/

http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/17652

http://slam.codeplex.com/

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Did you explore using SharePoint List directly in SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

You are mentioning "import" so by definition it means taking data over. On the other hand, except for the SSIS packages, I personally haven't heard of a capacity of SSAS to be able to define cube on volatile data - e.g. real-time feeds (but again, maybe I'm wrong!)

Are you aware that SharePoint server also has its own tools for business-intelligence, which allow direct building KPI, scorecards and dashboard with SharePoint lists? Have you looked at using PerformancePoint designer to directly build BI solutions ? 
Did you tried also using PowerPivot (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413413.aspx), but in the context of a SharePoint ?

Comment: Hello Marius, Thanks for reply, I know PowerPivot, but I have to develop SSRS Report, SilverLight Dashboard and HTML5 + CSS3 lightweight web for portable devices for same SharePoint List with some complex output for which I have written MDX. and currently I am using SSIS package (http://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2011/06/how-to-use-a-sharepoint-list-as-a-data-source-in-your-ssis-package/) but not satisfied that much. so I am searching alternate tools